# How to show the numbers of answers posted into my forum?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

i'm making a forum using Java technologies. Actually it is almost near to complete but the problem is I want to show numbers of answer into my forum. Okay let's understand in deeply.

Firstly, i've created a file named as `index.jsp` where we could see all questions. For `e.g` Have a look into stackoverflow.com we see all question as well `numbers of answers posted` in one question. That's all i wanted to show into my index.jsp.

I'm fetching all questions using `select * from question_table..`. Actually into my `view question` file. I'm fetching the answer using `question_id` table which is created into `answer's table`. You know very well to show answer in particular  we need to save the same `question_id` into answer's table as well question's table.

For `e.g:`

look at this table i designed the same thing:

```
create table if not exists thread_question(
question_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
question_title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
question VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
question_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(question_id)
);

create table if not exists thread_answer(
answer_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
question_id INT NOT NULL references thread_question(question_id),
answer VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
answer_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(answer_id)
);
```

As well you could see here, `question_id` is saved into two tables. Same process i'm using here.

Now i want to show my number of answers into my main page. Any idea? what can be used here. I really stuck here. Please help!

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

***EDITED:***

Here is my full codes of table:

```
create table if not exists thread_question(
question_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
question_title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
question VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
question_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(question_id)
);

create table if not exists thread_answer(
answer_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
question_id INT NOT NULL references thread_question(question_id),
first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
answer VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
answer_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(answer_id)
);
```

Here is [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWInK.png).

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Can you not select count(*) from thread_answer ta, thread_question tq where ta.question_id = tq.question_id?

Comment: what is `ta` and `tq`? Can you please explain me?

Comment: They are alias for the table. You can create shorten names for your tables inside the query just to make it easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use inner join to fetch number of answer per question

```
   SELECT thread_question.question_id, COALESCE(sub.counts,0) AS NumerOfAnswer 
   FROM thread_question LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT question_id, COUNT(answer_id) AS counts
        FROM thread_answer
        GROUP BY question_id
    ) sub ON thread_question.question_id = sub.question_id
  ORDER BY NumerOfAnswer
```

Comment: Hey.. it worked!!! :) thank you .... Thank you so much.. can you tell me? how do you know these queries??? I'm a student.. I'm the best in Java but not in `MySql` Please tell me.. how do you know all these???

Comment: One more thing .. i want to know... Your sql is working fine.. but these values are showing `line wise` but i want to show it using `desc` .. is it posiible?

Comment: Use Order by Clause, so add this in query at last   order by NumerOfAnswer desc. See modified answer

Comment: I did it... remove `desc`

Comment: from `order by` line.. Thanks you..you're genius in `SQL`.. I must admit it :)

Comment: by default the order by clause return ascending order(low to high), if you want display(high to low) use desc at last.. I thing you want decrement order so I add that, but I think you need asc then just remove desc from last, worked fine

Answer (score 0):

The count of all answers in the entire forum?

```
SELECT COUNT(answer_id)
FROM thread_answer
```

Display number of answers in a query that fetches questions for display?

```
SELECT <...your selected columns...>, COALESCE(a.counts, 0) AS counts
FROM thread_question q
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT question_id, COUNT(answer_id) AS counts
        FROM thread_answers
        GROUP BY question_id
    ) a ON q.question_id = a.question_id
```