# Combine two select statement in MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jsp

I've this table, Have a look there.

```
create table if not exists thread_question
   (
    question_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    question_title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    question VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
    question_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(question_id)
  );

create table if not exists thread_answer
 (
  answer_id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  question_id INT NOT NULL references thread_question(question_id),
  first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  answer VARCHAR(100000) NOT NULL,
  answer_dateTime VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(answer_id)
 );
```

Actually i'm making a forum to show answers, it is working perfect. You could see as well `question_id`'s column is inserted in `thread_question` as well `thread_answer`. I wanted to show my answers in one page that how many users has posted there answer.

So i could do that according to this question -> [How to show the numbers of answers posted into my forum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844185/how-to-show-the-numbers-of-answers-posted-into-my-forum)

***Question***

Now I'm trying to combine these two statements:

**First statement :**

```
SELECT thread_question.question_id, COALESCE(sub.counts,0) AS NumerOfAnswer 
   FROM thread_question LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT question_id, COUNT(answer_id) AS counts
        FROM thread_answer
        GROUP BY question_id
    ) sub ON thread_question.question_id = sub.question_id ORDER BY NumerOfAnswer asc
```

**Second statement :**

```
select * from thread_question
```

Actually i want to fetch `user's first and second name`, `question` and `question's title` from `thread_question's table`.

I do use `UNION and UNION ALL` and `SELECT( SELECT..)(SELECT..)`.
 But i'm unable to show the result. It's giving me an error everytime.

PLEASE HELP!!
Surely, help would be appreciated!!

Comment: what error you are getting while running the statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `thread_question` table in the query, all you need to do to bring the remaining columns is to add `thread_question.*`, like this:

```
SELECT
    thread_question.* -- <<== Use .* to bring all fields
,   COALESCE(sub.counts,0) AS NumerOfAnswer 
FROM thread_question
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT question_id, COUNT(answer_id) AS counts
    FROM thread_answer
    GROUP BY question_id
) sub ON thread_question.question_id = sub.question_id
ORDER BY NumerOfAnswer asc
```

Comment: You're `GOOD` ......AWESOME ANSwER man.... Can you tell me please ..how do you know all these SQL??... I want to be perfect in it.. I'm good in JAVA.. please tell me

Comment: @snehamathur Unfortunately, there's only one way - write a lot of SQL.